# App ends on Button Click

Tags: android, database

My program contains an activity to save place and date to database. But the app unfortunately  ends while clicking in the ok button.here are the codes with logcat

FirstActivity.java

```
package example.showevent1;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class FirstActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public TextView userSelection;
    public EditText userText;
    private static final String[] items={"Yalahanka","Rajai nagar","Sivaji Nagar","Koramangala","RT Nagar", "Banashankari","Yashwanthpura","Hebbal"};
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    public FirstActivity(){

    }

    public FirstActivity(TextView userSelection2, EditText userText2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.userSelection=userSelection;
        this.userText=userText;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        userSelection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        userText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         Spinner my_spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);//data1
        my_spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter aa=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        my_spin.setAdapter(aa);



    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
        userSelection.setText(items[pos]);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        userSelection.setText("");
    }
    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.userSelection.toString();
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this.userText.toString();
    }

    public void add_data(View v){
        db.addContact(new FirstActivity(userSelection,userText) );
    }
    }
```

> DatePickerFragment.java

```
package example.showevent1;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

database handler. I used only addcontact and getcontact methods

```
package example.showevent1;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(FirstActivity contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    FirstActivity getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        FirstActivity contact = new FirstActivity();
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
 /*   public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }     */

    // Updating single contact
   /* public int updateContact(FirstActivity contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }*/

    // Deleting single contact
 /*   public void deleteContact(FirstActivity contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }*/


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

activity_first.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/color_1"
    tools:context=".FirstActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:background="#ffff99"
        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
        android:text="@string/dt"
        android:textColor="#b22924" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text="@string/select"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="#b22924"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#ffff99"
        android:textColor="#b22924" 
        android:fadingEdge=""/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1"
        android:background="#ffff99"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:onClick="add_data" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> logcat

```
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     ... 11 more
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at example.showevent1.FirstActivity.getName(FirstActivity.java:57)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at example.showevent1.DatabaseHandler.addContact(DatabaseHandler.java:63)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at example.showevent1.FirstActivity.add_data(FirstActivity.java:64)
08-02 06:54:04.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Why do you need constructor for activity? Remove this: `public FirstActivity(TextView userSelection2, EditText userText2)` block.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText clearly shows the error

Answer (score 1):

Check this error message in your Logcat `android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText`

Go to the line 36 of your `FirstActivity.java`. There you would be trying to something like

`userText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);`

Here the `R.id.editText1` seems to be of type Button. Check if you are using the correct id in this case as in the name you specified in the XML layout file is same as the one you are trying to use.

Comment: Null Pointer at `FirstActivity.getName(FirstActivity.java:57)` What is on that line?

Comment: is `newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");` on line 57?

Answer (score 0):

Try clean your project. Sometimes after layout change project building is broken.
And it's definetly a bad practise to store data in an Activity class, you should create a new class to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor assigns userSelection and userText to themselves rather than the passed in values:

```
public FirstActivity(TextView userSelection2, EditText userText2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.userSelection=userSelection;
    this.userText=userText;
}
```

This is causing the null pointer you see, as you're creating a new Activity with the constructor but not assigning the values that you're giving it.

Step 1: Get rid of the Activity constructors.  You shouldn't be using a new instance of Activity as a holder for some contact data and it's causing this cascading series of Exceptions.

Instead of passing in the whole Activity, pass in only the String values of the TextView or EditTexts that you want to save to the database, or create a new "Contact" class to hold the state.